# After Upgrading to 1.6, Angular error messages aren't showing

Tags: angularjs, debugging, angularjs-1.6

I upgraded my large app from 1.4 to 1.6 recently.  Ever since the upgraded, some extremely helpful debug/error messages aren't showing.

For example, if I forget an injection, there's no error message, however the app won't load.

If I try to do any large changes, my app won't load because of some angular-centric issue, but I normally won't be able to find the issue since there's no console message.

**Edit**
I'm also not getting error messages for circular dependencies.  The app just won't load in this case, either.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how can i get the old error messages that existed in <1.4 (I believe they were compile errors).

Comment: Thank you! I'm having this same problem. Thanks for being a douche georgeawg. Maybe he doesn't have a specific question but you can easily understand the problem.

Comment: Also having this problem.  Upgraded from 1.5 to 1.6 and started noticing no errors if controller or service does not exist or is improperly injected.

Comment: @Mastro Thanks for calling out georgeawg, but I'm a she.

Comment: Haha sorry, never checked the name. Are you using KendoUI any chance? I'm wondering if it's related. We tried to re-create it on plunker and couldn't. So it might be something related to the project or custom handlers. Still need to dig into it more.

Comment: @Mastro not using KendoUI, we are using jquery (as much as I hate it), though.  We actually don't have many third-party libraries on our project.  I'm wondering if it has to do with Bugsnag.  I've never had a problem with it before, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally figured this out ourselves. Thought I'd come back and share.

We had to modify a config on the main module. Here's the code example. Give it a try. Unless you figured out something else.

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(true);
}]);
```

Comment: Circling back to this -- I'm now seeing errors (injections, nullables) not being thrown when called via a route resolve, have you witnessed this?  We're still on 1.6.